# Karma tests does not seem to load my Angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, testing, controller, karma-runner

I run my angular tests with karma, my application is running fine in browser, but tests fails and I am suspecting wrong settings.

Here are the controllers and tests :

```
// app/scripts/controllers/main.js

'use strict';

angular.module('GloubiBoulgaClientApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

  });
```

Here is the test file :

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('GloubiBoulgaClientApp'));

  var MainCtrl,
    scope;  

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));  

  it('should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope', function () {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

The karma conf

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '', 

    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'app/scripts/*.js',
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],  

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [], 

    // web server port
    port: 8080,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

The error ouput

```
 PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Linux) Controller: MainCtrl should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope FAILED
         Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
         http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8-build.2094+sha.b6c42d5/ng/areq?p0=MainCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got% 2
 0undefined
             at assertArg (--obfuscated-path--GloubiBoulga/GloubiBoulgaClient/app/bower_components/angular/angula
 r.js:1362)
             at assertArgFn (--obfuscated-path--GloubiBoulga/GloubiBoulgaClient/app/bower_components/angular/angu
 lar.js:1373)
             at --obfuscated-path--GloubiBoulga/GloubiBoulgaClient/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6763
             at --obfuscated-path--GloubiBoulga/GloubiBoulgaClient/test/spec/controllers/main.js:15
             at invoke (--obfuscated-path--GloubiBoulga/GloubiBoulgaClient/app/bower_components/angular/angular.j
 s:3704)
             at workFn (--obfuscated-path--GloubiBoulga/GloubiBoulgaClient/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular -mocks.js:2120)
```

I am wondering why this happen, I tried to find some documentation about the karma initialization with angularjs. But the most documentation I found is only dummy tutorial that are repeating the same pattern ( like the dummy todo list, but with phones ... )

It seem that $controllerProvide.register fails to resolve my controllers name.
But Directives tests are working correctly ...

Thanks for your attention.

Edit Notes : I replaced the controller PersonCtrl by MainCtrl in this thread because It was confusing people about where to look. Now MainCtrl is the simpliest failing example I found.

**This issue is only affecting my controllers, ( all of them ), but tests for Services and  Directives are working as expected**

Comment: Try : moving your variable `Person` out of `beforeEach()`, because module `Person` should be defined first

Comment: Just edited the code. As you can see, the issue still the same.

Comment: I changed the example. And used really dummy code to avoid missleading

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved my problem, I've spent nearly a week to figure why this was not working.

I'd like to warn you, that **Karma Stacktrace and error reports**, even in debug mode, were not showing clues and **were mainly missleading**.
I've spent time in javascript debugger jumping frame to frame, to understand why my controllers where not loaded. ( Inspecting Angular's controllers register, shown it was empty)

While digging in my directories I've found a *.js that were not loaded in the index in production but by the globbing pattern in tests.

**It was my old http_interceptor service that I moved but did not trashed the file.
Removing this buggy file fixed the weird Karma/Jasmine/Angular behaviour.**

Lesson learned :
Do not trust tests output ( but what should I trust then ? ).
Remove files you are not using/testing.

Thanks to everyone who tryied to solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you!  I have just been trying to debug why tests with Controller As syntax were not working.  (It turns out they were fine ;-) Your post prompted me to check what karma.conf was loading and I noticed that I needed to add angular-route.js and app.routes.js.  Phew!

Answer (score 8):

i think the main problem is coming from the karma conf :

```
files: [
      'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'app/scripts/*.js',
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'app/scripts/**/**/*.js',
      'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],
```

removing the * and specifying files one by one in the correct order, because if one is loaded before another it can break.

Edit : Add your files in the same order as your index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer unfortunately it lack explanations.
And do not fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this try.
But I ran Karma in debug with phantom and chrome to check what happen.

Files are loaded in the expected order. ( as listed above ).

I just set a breakpoint where I use the $controller() function.
But it does not find the MainCtrl 

I am wondering how I can instrospect my current context in order list available constructor symbol ( like 'MainCtrl' )

Comment: if you stick a debugger at the top of the app/scripts/controllers/main.js file, can you see karma stop at it? i.e. are you sure it was actually run ?

Comment: No it does not evaluates this file.
The file is loaded but it is not evaluated.
Why is what I do not understand, and still looking for ... :( This is really frustrating

Answer (score 1):

looking at this I'm wondering if the error message is confusing things.

in the stack trace i can see

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'scope.awesomeThings.length')
```

and from the example it does seem as though you have not defined any properties on the scope in your controller.

do you still have the problem if you add

```
$scope.awesomeThings = [];
```

to your controller?

Comment: Even with expect true to be true it will fail.
The problem is mostly that $controllerProvider.register() fail to resolve my controllers names.
As if the controllers where not loaded.

I'll update my exmaples again.

Comment: I replaced the expectation part to isolate the weird behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest [angular](http://angularjs.org/) and also using the [angular-route module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute),  you should include the angular-route script in the karma conf file too:

```
files: [
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'app/scripts/*.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'app/scripts/**/**/*.js',
  'test/mock/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'
],
```

I had this problem and adding it to the karma file did the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunatly it is not the issue, since I do not use the ng-route module.

My controller are loaded by the test browser, but never get evaluated.
This is my issue, and it still open ;)

Comment: I see. I had the same issue and the web search led me to this thread.
Although it's not the solution for you, I'm not going to delete my answer in the hope that it will help other newcomers to this thread with the same issue as I had. good luck in discovering a solution to your problem!

Comment: By "do not use it" I mean not in particular way, it is just included n  my app, used routeParams in some services.